# UISearchbar and passing data in View a controller xcode swift

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uisearchbar

So I have a table view and a searchbar, I implemented the code for the searchbar to filter my array it works just fine but when I click on the cell that I searched it doesn’t display the right information it displays only the information of the first row( first index), note I’m using the global array to pass data from my table view to the View controller so can someone tell me where is my problem in this code how can I solve it .

```
class SciencesVC: UIViewController ,UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UISearchBarDelegate{

    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
    @IBOutlet weak var TableView: UITableView!

    var data = ["د.غادة المطيري", "د.حياة سندي"]

    var filteredData = [String]()
    var inSearchMode = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        TableView.delegate = self
        TableView.dataSource = self
        searchBar.delegate = self
        searchBar.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.done

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if inSearchMode {

            return filteredData.count
        }

        return data.count

    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as? DataCell {

            let text: String!

            if inSearchMode {

                text = filteredData[indexPath.row]

            } else {

                text = data[indexPath.row]
            }

            cell.congigureCell(text: text)

            return cell

        } else {

            return UITableViewCell()
        }

    }
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

        if searchBar.text == nil || searchBar.text == "" {

            inSearchMode = false

            view.endEditing(true)

            TableView.reloadData()

        } else {

            inSearchMode = true

            filteredData = data.filter({$0.contains(searchBar.text!)})

            TableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){

        myIndex =  indexPath.row

        performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: self)
    }
}
```

Values are a global array in SciencesVC:

```
var Names = ["د.غادة المطيري ","د.حياة سندي "]
var majors = ["الكيمياء","عالمة صيدلية "]
var Communiction = ["-","-",""]
var myIndex = 0
```

*here is the the Detailed UIViewController to show the the information*

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var Name: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var myImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var major: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var info: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var twitter: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        Name.text = Names[myIndex]
        info.text = infos [myIndex]
        myImageView.image = UIImage(named: Names[myIndex] + ".png")
        twitter.text = Communiction[myIndex]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I’m on my iPhone but try it:
In `didSelectRowAt`, you have to check if you are filtering with searchBar or not.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){

if inSearchMode {
                myIndex =  data.index(of: filteredData[indexPath.row])
            } else {
                myIndex =  indexPath.row
            }

        performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: self)
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much it works now i am so grateful for your help seriously you made my day

Comment: @ameerahalharbi Glad to help you ! Please mark my answer as checked.

Comment: This is a much more elegant answer than mine! :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)` method to send the necessary index to the detailViewController.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)

    guard let detailViewController = segue.destination as? UIViewController else { fatalError() }

    guard let selectedCell = sender as? TableViewCell else { fatalError() }

    guard let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: selectedCell) else { fatalError() }

    if inSearchMode {
        selectedIndex = data.index(of: filteredData[indexPath.row])!
    } else {
        selectedIndex = indexPath.row
    }

    detailViewController.myIndex = selectedIndex

}
```